# ros2 import tf2_geometry_msgs

Tags: ros, python, ros2, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I am unable to import  tf2_geometry_msgs  as an python3 module in ros2 eloquent.
Only tf2_ros, tf2_py and tf2_msgs seem to be a python module.
I am porting an melodic project to eloquent and we used the comfortable do_transform_vector3 function of that script.
Someone else seems to have a similar issue with c++: [link](https://answers.ros.org/question/344496/cannot-include-tf2_geometry_msgsh/) (Maybe its completely unrelated though)

Am I missing something here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360019/ros2--import-tf2_geometry_msgs/) by [.zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/40609/.zero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2020-08-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The python part of `tf2_geometry_msgs` has not been ported to ROS 2 yet. There's more info here: https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/issues/285#issuecomment-670073323

In short, it's not importable because the ROS 2 version of `python_orocos_kdl` has not been ported.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0